# solution of the equation $x^{22}\equiv{2}\pmod {23}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x^{22}\equiv{2}\pmod {23}$ does  this  have  a  solution?

By  Euler's  formula  since  $23$  is  a  prime  $x^{22}\equiv {1}\pmod {23}$  is  true . But  is  this  enough  to  dismiss  the  possibility  of the  equation  $x^{22}\equiv {2}\pmod {23}$ having  a  solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x$ is relatively prime to $23$, then as you point out Euler's formula will give you $x^{22} \equiv 1$. Since $1 \not \equiv 2$, no such $x$ can be a solution.

But, $23$ is prime! So the only case where $x$ is not relatively prime to $23$ is $x \equiv 0 \pmod{23}$, in which case we have $x^{22} \equiv 0$, and $0 \not \equiv 2$.